# CSS image effect with 2 transitions on hover

Tags: css, css-transitions

Is there a proper and smooth CSS solution for a CSS image hover effect that deals with 2 transitions:

- brighten the image itself on hover using background-color and opacity
- set the playbutton opacity to 100% on hover

my solution's not perfect, the play button's still flickering and not animated smooth.
i'm looking for a cross browser solution as well...

feel free to see my example and what i tried at https://codepen.io/marcusegger/pen/WNReBpa because it's not so easy to explain.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 mt-5">
      <div class="imgContainer position-relative">
        <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/25/21/20/ipad-649499_1280.jpg" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgContainer {
  background: #293D4F;
}

.imgContainer img  { 
    opacity: .25;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.imgContainer::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    content: url(https://www.daslandhilft.de/assets/img/play.svg);
    opacity: .5;
}

.imgContainer:hover::before {
    content: url(https://www.daslandhilft.de/assets/img/play.svg);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `pointer-events: none` inside `.imgContainer:hover::before`, due to 'interferences' with the `hover` attribute of its children element `img`. So it should look like this:

```
.imgContainer {
  background: #293D4F;
}

.imgContainer img  { 
    opacity: .25;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.imgContainer::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    content: url(https://www.daslandhilft.de/assets/img/play.svg);
    opacity: .5;
}

.imgContainer:hover::before {
    content: url(https://www.daslandhilft.de/assets/img/play.svg);
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: oh cool, didn't know that! do you have a solution for the same transition timing for the image transition and the play-button transition? my goal is to have a smooth hover effect with the image itself and the playbutton as well....

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry @michbeck. I've been out for some days and didn't saw your question. I guess you've already got a solution for this. If not, let me know and I'll try to help you.

Comment: got it already, yeah: my fault was to user::before instead of ::after thanks for your help"